# Bootstrap Form Theme Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm using Bootstrap 3 theme in my symfony project like this :

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
```

I want to surround all my forms with a < div > like this :

```
< div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" >
    {{ form(my_form) }}
< /div >
```

I have so many forms in my Symfony application so i don't want to write that < div > on each form file

Is there a way to do that by overriding a little bit of the "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" file and keep it's original content ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own form theme, that extends and overrides a small part of the original Symfony-sourced theme file.

Note that the 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' theme file extends from another file, so you may have to search up the inheritance tree to find the most appropriate block to override.

Comment: i already tried it but it didn't work , i tried it using {%block form%} < div class="...." > {{ parent() }} < /div > {%endblock%} , what should i write in this custom form ?

Comment: How are you setting the `form_themes` config, and using the parent within your own code?

Comment: i made a copy of the "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" file in " app/Ressources/Form " and added that bit of code at the end of file